# NodeJs Glob dont show files/folders in Drive Disk on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I want to get a folders hierarchy tree from the Drive Disk until the last subfolder.

```
Disk Drive
-First Folder
---Subfolder One
---Subfolder Two
-Second Folder
---Subfolder One
-Nth Folder
---Subfolder One
---Subfolder N
```

I will input what folder I want to inspect (this part is working in glob):

```
    let mg = new Glob('C:/Program Files/*', { mark: true }, function (err, matches) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('folders', matches);
        }
    });
```

Glob will not show what folders are in a Disk Drive:

```
    let mg = new Glob('C:/*', { mark: true }, function (err, matches) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('folders', matches);
        }
    });
```

Res:

```
files []
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I used *child_process* to call cmd commands and find the subfolders of the Local Drives.
I think *child_process* has a promise module, when I will find a cleaner version of the code I will update.

```js
const child = require('child_process');

let pathLetter: '';

function asyncGetAllFolders() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    child.exec(
      `cd /d ${pathLetter}:/ && dir ${pathLetter}: /b /ad`,
      (error, stdout) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          next(error);
        } else {
          allFoldersList = stdout.split('\r\n').map((value) => value.trim());
          resolve('done!');
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

function asyncGetHiddenFolders() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    child.exec(
      `cd /d ${pathLetter}:/ && dir ${pathLetter}: /b /ah`,
      (error, stdout) => {
        if (error) {
          next(error);
        } else {
          hiddenFolderList = stdout
            .split('\r\n')
            .map((value) => value.trim());
          resolve('done!');
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

async function extractUniqueFolders() {
  await asyncGetAllFolders();
  await asyncGetHiddenFolders();

  hiddenFolderList.forEach((item) => {
    if (allFoldersList.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
      allFoldersList.splice(allFoldersList.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  });
}
```